# how to pass pointcloud from the callback function in subscriber

Tags: ros, kinect, callback, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Aim-Subscribe to pointcloud from kinect and access it from main() function

I created a class and callback function as its member function.

I am able to subscribe to the pointcloud data from kinect using

```
 ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/camera/depth_registered/points", 3,&pass_cloud::callback,&cloud1);
```

I am the changing the member value by the callback but i am not able to see it working.

You can find my code here..Please let me know what changes can be done
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95042389/sampl.cpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54563/how-to-pass-pointcloud-from-the-callback-function-in-subscriber/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Avoid global variables. it is bad practice. here is how you could do it:

```
class pass_cloud
{
public:
pass_cloud (ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh), i(0)
{
  sub = nh_.subscribe ("/camera/depth_registered/points",     3,&pass_cloud::callback,this);
} // your constructor and store the passed node handle (nh) to your class attribute nh_ 

void callback (const pcl::PointCloud& cloud) 
{
 input= cloud; // copy the variable that the callback passes in to you class variable (attribute) input
 i=i+1;
}

process()
{
//You might want to add an if statement here to only print if the input is not empty, I am not sure how but something like this if(input is not empty){
std::cout << " " << input.points[i].x << " " << input.points[i].y <<  " " << input.points[i].z << std::endl; std::cout<<"reached here"<<std::endl; 

}

void spin ()
{
 ros::Rate rate (30);
 while (ros::ok ())
 {
 ros::spinOnce ();
 rate.sleep ();
 }
}

protected: // Your class attributes
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
pcl::PointCloud& input;
cloud ros::Subscriber sub;
int i;
}; // end of class

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "pointcloud_node");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

pass_cloud* node = 0;

node = new pass_cloud(nh);

node->spin (); 
return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-02-07**:
This is very nice but I have some basic questions to ask. could you give your email id

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-07**:
I am not a ROS expert as I only started learning ROS less than 2 months ago. But I will be happy to help if can. My email is khalid.ayousif@hotmail.com

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-02-07**:
Hi, if possible , could you see the code at this link and tell what might be wrong https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95042389/sampl.cpp

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-07**:
In your code, it is being stuck in a for loop, without updating your cloud. I do not think you need a for loop since ros::spin() is already constantly looping until you press ctrl+c, I have updated my code in my answer to your case. Copy and paste it and see if it works. let me know